# Snort3: Where is the default implementation for MpseMatch?

Tags: search-engine, snort

I'm trying to implement a custom search engine plugin for `snort3`. For now, I'm just trying to mimic the behavior of the [`snort3_extra`](https://github.com/snort3/snort3_extra) example ([`lowmem`](https://github.com/snort3/snort3_extra/tree/master/src/search_engines/lowmem)).

However, I hit a roadblock. The inherited [`_search`](https://github.com/snort3/snort3_extra/blob/b81e2e4f9296d9ae724e8d1b409371a3715fc2cc/src/search_engines/lowmem/lowmem.cc#L65C9-L65C16) function has a side effect happening inside of it. I have narrowed it down to the call to the `MpseMatch` function in [snort3_extra/src/search_engines/lowmem/sfksearch.cc](https://github.com/snort3/snort3_extra/blob/b81e2e4f9296d9ae724e8d1b409371a3715fc2cc/src/search_engines/lowmem/sfksearch.cc#L579):

```cpp
if (match (pk->user, pk->rule_option_tree, index, context, pk->neg_list) > 0)
```

The `MpseMatch` function has the following signature, and is defined in [snort3/src/search_engines/search_common.h](https://github.com/snort3/snort3/blob/be0977a3a8a98632e5cd1238c1d0da6dc2693b5f/src/search_engines/search_common.h#L39):

```cpp
typedef int (* MpseMatch)(void* user, void* tree, int index, void* context, void* list);
```

Since `lowmem` doesn't implement its own version of `MpseMatch`, it has to use the default version. I wasn't able to figure out where it [resides](https://github.com/snort3/snort3). Please help.

Also, where can I find a good documentation source for `snort3_extra`? The best one I could find is [this](https://fossies.org/dox/snort3_extra-3.1.78.0/classLowmemMpse.html) one, but it seems auto-generated.

Thank you!